# 1 of my fixtures in bathroom is flickering

Tags: light, circuit

1 of my light fixtures is flickering. Other light which is using same circuit is ok. when I turn on hairdryer on the same circuit then flickering is even more visible (while other light is still Ok).
House is from 2008 but I also feel that it is cheaply made.
Do you have any recommendations what to do with it? Thanks

Comment: What is the type of light bulb/s?  LEDs have more problems with flickering with changes in power use.  I would turn off the breaker for that circuit, do not trust turning off the power just by the switch, and check all the wire connections and light bulb is still tight.  Loose connection might cause the flickering also.

Comment: Tried swapping the bulbs over?

Comment: I have led bulb in both fixtures (they are on separate switch). I tried different led bulbs but results are the same. I will have to check connections in switch and fixture.

Comment: After checking those connections, figure out if there’s a gfci receptacle that feeds power, and check the connections there. It’s also possible (though not super likely) that it’s the gfci itself.